# Rails 4 - trouble with two associations, same model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scaffolding, rails-migrations

I'm trying to make a simple movie database using Rails 4.0.0 as a learning project. I'm particularly interested in using scaffolding as much as possible, as this is one of the features that drew me to RoR in the first place.

Yes, I do realize the [potential risks](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/book/ruby-on-rails-tutorial#cha-beginning) (Box 1.2.Scaffolding: Quicker, easier, more seductive), but I promise I won't have my project go public before I *really* understand what's going on beneath the hood. Right now I'm more in "evaluating technologies for my next super duper project"-mode.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
rails g scaffold Person name:string
rails g scaffold Movie name:string
```

Now, I could've done something like

```
rails g scaffold Movie name:string person_id:integer
```

instead, but I want a movie to be associated with both a director and an actor. (Next step is to make an association that relates multiple actors to a single movie, but I'm not quite there yet.)

So, I headed over to the blog post [Creating Multiple Associations With the Same Table](http://www.spacevatican.org/2008/5/6/creating-multiple-associations-with-the-same-table/), describing pretty much what I need. It's a somewhat old post, so things might have changed now - I don't know. Anyway. This how I changed the models:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :movies
end
```

and

```
class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :director_id, :class_name => 'Person', :foreign_key => 'person_id'
    belongs_to :actor_id, :class_name => 'Person', :foreign_key => 'actor_id'
end
```

and finally the magical

```
rake db:migrate
```

Starting the WEBrick by running `rails s` in the console, I open my browser and start registering people

[image]

The time has come to start registering movies. According to previous questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8420769/rails-how-to-migrate-a-database-where-i-added-a-belongs-to-relationship) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4619651/how-to-reflect-in-the-database-a-new-belongs-to-and-has-many-relationship-in-rub) I have to make a migration script in order to create the necessary database fields. So this is what I did:

```
rails g migration AddPersonIdsToMovies director_id:integer actor_id:integer
```

I also updated the `app/views/movies/_form.html.erb` to

```
<%= form_for(@movie) do |f| %>
  <% if @movie.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@movie.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this movie from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @movie.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
    <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :director_id %><br>
    <%= f.select :director_id, Person.all.collect {|x| [x.name, x.id]}, {}, :multiple => false %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :actor_id %><br>
    <%= f.select :actor_id, Person.all.collect {|x| [x.name, x.id]}, {}, :multiple => false %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

When I create a new movie, the view shows up fine and the select inputs works fine. However, the data in the director and actor field isn't persisted. I ran `rails console` and looked at the newly created movie:

```
irb(main):004:0> mov = Movie.first
Movie Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "movies".* FROM "movies" ORDER BY "movies"."id" 
ASC LIMIT 1 => #<Movie id: 1, name: "No such movie", created_at: 
"2013-08-02 17:02:12", updated_at: "2013-08-02 17:02:12", 
director_id: nil, actor_id: nil>
```

which is kind'a disappointing with no director or actor info.

**Update**

Based on @Mattherick's suggesition, I edited the private part of the `movies_controller.rb` to this:

```
# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def movie_params
  params.require(:movie).permit(:name, :director_id, :actor_id)
end
```

Unfortunately, when I post a new movie I get

> Person(#70319935588740) expected, got String(#70319918738480)
>
> Extracted source:
>
> ```
> # POST /movies.json
> def create
>   @movie = Movie.new(movie_params)
>
> respond_to do |format|
>   if @movie.save
> ```

and the request data goes as

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"???",
 "movie"=>{"name"=>"Romantic Comedy",
 "director_id"=>"2",
 "actor_id"=>"1"},
 "commit"=>"Create Movie"}

**Update 2**

I tried to create a new Movie in the rails console, like this:

```
irb(main):001:0> movie = Movie.new(name: "My fine movie", director_id: "1", actor_id: "2")
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch: Person(#70311109773080) expected, got String(#70311102311480)
```

which is what you'd expect from the POST to the controller. This made me test what happened if I excluded the quotation marks for `director_id` and `actor_id`. So I did

```
irb(main):005:0> movie = Movie.new(name: "My fine movie", director_id: 1, actor_id: 2)
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch: Person(#70282707507880) expected, got Fixnum(#70282677499540)
```

Still using the console, I decided to create an actor and a director

```
director = Person.new(name: "Woody Allen")
director.save
actor = Person.new(name: "Arnold Schwarzenegger")
actor.save
```

and then I did

```
movie = Movie.new(name: "I'd like to see that", director_id: director, actor_id: actor)
movie.save
```

which worked like a charm (output omitted for brevity). So the whole question boils down to **"How can I pass a Person as the argument to `director_id` and `actor_id` through the web interface?"**

If I had a single field in Movies called `person_id: integer`, I believe that rails would've inferred that I'm not trying to pass a string containing the id of a person, but rather I'm trying to pass an entire person object.

**Update 3**

I tested my suspicion that rails understands how to deal with posts when the foreign key column is named after the pattern [table]_id. So I created a new project with a `Continent` model and a `Country` model, where `rails g scaffold Country name:string continent_id:integer`. I changed my `Country` view to include

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :continent_id %><br>
  <%= f.select :continent_id, Continent.all.collect {|x| [x.name, x.id]} %>
</div>
```

instead of the default numeric field. The `continent_id` is still posted a string:

```
Started POST "/countries" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-03 10:40:40 +0200
Processing by CountriesController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"???", "country"=>{"name"=>"Uganda", "continent_id"=>"4"}, "commit"=>"Create Country"}
```

yet rails understood that `continent_id` was the identifier of an entry in the `Continent` table.

Sadly, the inferrer mechanism doesn't work in my original case, as I have two associations from `Movie` to the `Person` table. I need to somehow make sure rails understand that there is a mapping from `director_id` to a `Person`.

**Update 4**

According to some sources, it seems as I need to refine the `Person` model further. So I did

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :directed_movies, :class_name => 'Movie', :foreign_key => 'director_id'
  has_many :acted_movies, :class_name => 'Movie', :foreign_key => 'actor_id'
end
```

but still not fixing my problems.

I'm kind'a lost. <del>Can anyone give me a few pointers on what I'm missing here?</del> Can anyone help me map from `director_id` to `person_id`? Thanks!

Comment: You have to add `accepts_nested_attributes_for :actor` and the same for director in the Movie model ;)

Comment: I think that you should use has_and_belongs_to_many relation, because movie has many actors and actor can appear in many movies

Comment: Which parameters do you get in your controller? Are you on rails 4? You also have to update your private method in your rails controller..in rails 4 only permitted parameters are allowed. @MrYoshiiji I don't think accepts_nested_attributes are necessary..

Comment: @Mattherick: oh, forgot to mention that - I'm running rails 4. Based on your suggestion, I tried permitting :director and :actor by saying  `params.require(:movie).permit(:name, :director, :actor)`, but now I get the following error: Person(#70318440095780) expected, got String(#70318417177660)

Comment: @MrYoshiji: I tried your suggestion, but to no avail ... but thanks for posting! :)

Comment: @Berlin: yeah, that's probably a great suggestion - but a little premature for my skills right now. ;)

Comment: add a debugger and check out your correct params. maybe you have to change :director to :director_id and :actor to :actor_id in your permit method.

Comment: The two foreign key you have set are not columns of the Movie model (shows director and actor columns). You have to add the 2 columns `person_id` and `actor_id` since you have declared these two foreign keys in the Movie model

Comment: btw: your migration rails g migration AddPersonIdsToMovies director:integer actor:integer -> should be changed to  director_id:integer actor_id:integer

Comment: @Mattherick yeah, that makes sense. I created the renaming migration, updated the movies/_form.html.erb and tried again. Now I'm back to getting the `Person expected, got string`-message. The debug info {"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"?????",
 "movie"=>{"name"=>"test2",
 "director_id"=>"2",
 "actor_id"=>"1"},
 "commit"=>"Create Movie"}

Comment: @MrYoshiji thanks for the suggestion - but I think the `rails g migration AddPersonIdsToMovies` (which is now replaced with :director_id and :actor_id fields) should create the fields in the database. At least that's what sqlite3's telling me.

Comment: Can you update your post with the relevant error/code parts?

Comment: Did you already changed your permit method in the controller? And in your model you should also set the right accessors. But as you see the params are correct. I think you nearly have fixed it :-)

Comment: @MrYoshiji yup - just did. :)

Comment: @Mattherick the controller's ok I think. I was under the impression that accessors aren't needed in rails 4. I tried adding `attr_accessible :director_id, :actor_id` and got "`attr_accessible` is extracted out of Rails into a gem. Please use new recommended protection model for params(strong_parameters) or add `protected_attributes` to your Gemfile to use old one." But maybe that's not what you meant? Yeah, it feels pretty close!!! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I finally got it. I don't think this is the correct way to go about this, but at least it solved the problem. As I mentioned in update 2, I was able to create a `Movie` object in the irb, and so I asked the question "How can I pass a Person as the argument to director_id and actor_id through the web interface?"

According to the sources [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5418756/two-has-may-association-with-same-model-rail-3?rq=1) and [elsewhere](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-belongs_to), rails should've understood the `has_many` and `belongs_to` class methods. However, I just can't seem to get it to work.

So I hacked the `create` method in `movies_controller.rb` to read like this:

```
def create
  director = Person.where(:id => movie_params[:director_id]).first
  actor = Person.where(:id => movie_params[:actor_id]).first
  @movie = Movie.new(name: movie_params[:name], director_id: director, actor_id: actor)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @movie.save
      format.html { redirect_to @movie, notice: 'Movie was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @movie }
    else
      format.html { render action: 'new' }
      format.json { render json: @movie.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

This is certainly not as elegant as I'd like it to be, and I don't think it is the RoR way to do things. Unfortunately it is the only thing I got working so far, but if anyone else can make a multiple association to the same model using rails 4, please do give me a heads up! :)